# What is the relation of the transition band's width and the filter order for the FIR windowing method

Tags: filter-design, window-functions

When designing an FIR filter using the windowing method, how can one estimate the filter order ? It's obvious that the type of window and the transitions band's width has some effect on the order.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are only heuristic formulas for estimating the filter order. For a Kaiser window (which is probably the most frequently used window for filter design) the required filter order can be estimated from [1]

$$M=\frac{A-8}{2.285\,\Delta\omega}\tag{1}$$

where $A=-20\log\delta$ ($\delta$ is the maximum deviation from the desired response), and $\Delta\omega$ is the (smallest) transition bandwidth. This formula is of course only valid for the approximation of ideal frequency selective filters (low pass, high pass, etc.). This formula is implemented in Matlab's `kaiserord.m` function.

[1] Oppenheim, Schafer, Buck, *Discrete-Time Signal Processing*, 2nd ed., p. 476

Comment: i dunno why, but when i look at the [MATLAB page](http://cens.ioc.ee/local/man/matlab/toolbox/signal/kaiserord.html), it shows $A-7.95$ in the numerator.  not a big difference, but a curiosity.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson: Maybe that was Kaiser's original formula, and Oppenheim / Schafer "improved" it; my `kaiserord.m` (octave) actually uses $A-8$; don't know about Matlab's current implementation.

Comment: the other numbers are exactly the same.  i know in that $\beta$ formula that one constant is the reciprocal of the number of dB per neper.  and, even though it's partly heuristic, i think there's gotta be something to the 2.285 number.

Comment: what's interesting is that while the Kaiser window does not provide for a difference in passband ripple $\delta_p$ and stopband ripple $\delta_s$, it can be compared to the O&S formula for FIR length for the Parks-McClellan.  $$ $$ Kaiser: $ M=\frac{-10\log_{10}(\delta_s^2) - 8}{2.285\, \Delta\omega}$ $$ $$ Parks-McClellan: $M=\frac{-10\log_{10}(\delta_s \delta_p) - 13}{2.324\, \Delta\omega}$ $$ $$where $M+1$ is the number of taps.  you can see that the P-McC does just a little better than the Kaiser (because dividing by 2.324 gets you fewer taps than dividing by 2.285), but is comparable.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson: Yeah, but for a windowing method, Kaiser does pretty well because for a given maximum error $\delta$ you can't do better than PMcC, which, as an iterative method, is of course much more complex than windowing.

Comment: Is there any real advantage to use a window approach over PMcC or Least Squares algorithms? My perception was the latter always outperform any window design approach, and I never had any issue with  algorithm complexity given the availability of the design algorithms available in Matlab and Python. I ask as I was under the assumption from what I have been exposed to that windows will always underperform for standard low pass implementations and are therefore reserved for use in special cases (although I am not really sure what those cases would be). Looking for thought correction here.

Comment: @DanBoschen: I think that would actually make for a good question here on DSP.SE! :)

Comment: @Matt L: Yes of course! Done