# Digital Filter Design Accuracy

Tags: filters, infinite-impulse-response, finite-impulse-response, least-squares, equalizer

Having only dealt with digital filter scarcely, the question dawned to me when I used the firls function in matlab to design an equalizer with a certain gain response.

In general, can we prescribe an arbitrary shape as the equalizer filter response and hope to obtain a FIR/IIR filter that matches this shape within a set accuracy?

[Filter Order Rule of Thumb](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/37646/filter-order-rule-of-thumb) explains the relationship between filter order and the required ripple, rejection and transition bandwidth. But my question is slightly different. The equalizer I'm designing doesn't have a stringent requirement on rejection or transition bandwidth, what matters is the in-band amplitude/phase matching the prescription. For example, the prescribed shape could be predominantly a simple straight line with a slope (to equalize linear gain slope), or more practically on top of that it could have slight perturbations here and there of higher orders. I'm thinking if a polynomial of a certain order can model the prescribed in-band shape, then the FIR would have require the same order. Question is, has this been studied before?