Least Squares vs Parks McClellan
Two linear phase FIR filter design algorithms for optimum design are the least squares algorithm (provided by the ‘firls’ function in MATLAB, Octave and Python’s scipy.signal), and the Parks McClellan or equiripple algorithm (provided by ‘firpm’ in MATLAB or ‘remez’ in Octave and scipy.signal).
I understand that least squares provides the minimum error from a target response in the least squared error sense, while Park McClellan provides the minimum peak error (and as a result will have a greater rms error).
In my own filter applications applicable to wireless communications I would always choose the lowest rms error solution (least squares) leading to best system level performance. Further the least squares algorithm results in filters that have a stopband roll off which is preferred for use in decimation applications due to limiting the amount of aliasing that could otherwise accumulate in band.
All that said, what are specific applications where the Parks McClellan result would be preferred over the least squares solution?

I like firls() better than firpm().  It behaves better for a really long filter with sharp cutoff performance.

From my own work, it's difficult to understand what a filter with a least square error of X looks like. For the PM, there are rules of thumb formulas for estimating the desired filter length given: transition width, stopband attenuation  and passband ripple.

@David Thanks for the thought. I use those same rules of thumb for least squares and in both cases it is close enough to get started and then may involve simple iteration with the actual result while adjusting the number of taps.  Out of all the estimators my favorite is fred harris' based on its simplicity and practical use: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/64668/21048

I think the desire to have an efficient algorithm for the design of digital FIR filters according to the Chebyshev (or minimax) criterion stems not so much from the practical need for such filters, but it was mainly inspired by the readily available optimal analog filter types. In the analog domain we have the Cauer (elliptic) filter, which is optimal in the Chebyshev sense and which has the smallest transition band and the smallest maximum error out of all other formula based optimal filters (Chebyshev I and II, Butterworth, and Bessel). Note that there is no formula-based method for designing least squares optimal analog filters, and using optimization routines was common only among specialists for very specific design goals (e.g., group delay equalization).
Since the Cauer filter was a standard go-to solution for many filtering applications, it seemed natural to try to design FIR filters according to the same optimality criterion.
Another reason for the ubiquity of the Parks-McClellan algorithm is the fact that Parks and McClellan not only published a mathematical description of their method, but they also published a Fortran program which enabled anybody to immediately compute optimal FIR filters without the need to write their own software. Some current filter design routines are still based off of that original Fortran code.
Does that mean that in practice there are always better alternatives to the Parks-McClellan filters? First of all, I think that there are applications for which the optimality criterion is not an essential factor. In these cases, the differences between least squares and Chebyshev optimal filters will not cause any relevant difference. Second, there is a (theoretical) scenario where optimal Chebyshev filters are the best choice: for frequency selective filters, when we expect narrowband interference of unknown frequency in the stopband(s), and we want the maximum possible attenuation. Note that only for interference close to the band edges will the Chebyshev filter actually be better than a least squares filter, because the least squares filter's attenuation increases away from the band edges and becomes greater than the attenuation of the Chebyshev filter.
Least squares filters minimize the energy/power in the stopbands, which is often a very meaningful criterion. Also, least squares filters are relatively easy to design. In the case of FIR filters we just need to solve a system of linear equations. Of course, for very high filter orders or for certain design specifications we may encounter numerical instabilities, but this is common to all numerical filter design routines.
Finally, I would like to point out that the least squares and the Chebyshev criteria are two extreme cases on a continuous scale of optimal filters. The optimal Chebyshev filter has a relatively large mean squared error, whereas the least squares optimal filter has a relatively large maximum error. We could design filters that are a trade-off between those two extremes, having a smaller mean squared error than the Chebyshev filter, and  a smaller maximum error than the optimal least squares filter. The figure below shows the maximum error $\epsilon_C$ versus the mean-squared error $\epsilon_{LS}$ for a specific lowpass filter design. The two endpoints correspond to the least squares and Chebyshev (Parks McClellan) solutions. The other points are obtained by a weighted combination of the two criteria.

The figure shows that a slight deviation from the optimal solution greatly reduces the other error measure. E.g., by allowing an increase in mean-squared error from $1.3\cdot 10^{-3}$ (optimal LS solution) to $1.9\cdot 10^{-3}$, we can increase the minimum stopband attenuation from $38\textrm{ dB}$ to $47\textrm{ dB}$, which is just $1.4\textrm{ dB}$ worse than the PM solution. Any other trade-of is of course possible.
The figure below shows three filters corresponding to the two endpoints in above figure, and to one of the "compromise" points in the middle. The compromise filter (shown in red) has a steep transition from passband to stopband, virtually as steep as the PM filter (yellow). Its maximum error is only very slightly larger than that of the PM filter, yet its stopband attenuation becomes much better towards higher frequencies, a bit similar to the LS filter (in blue).

Another way to combine the two criteria is to use a constrained least-squares design, which minimizes the mean-squared error subject to a constraint on the maximum error. The figure below shows an example of a bandpass filter designed according to a constrained least-squares criterion. The stopband attenuation was constrained to be at least $60 \textrm{ dB}$.

Summarizing, I believe that for many applications the Chebyshev criterion is probably not the best choice. There are several cases where the least squares criterion is a better fit for the problem. However, I also believe that there are applications where the design criterion is not extremely relevant. Finally, mixing both criteria can be a good solution when maximum error as well as error energy should be considered.

@DanBoschen: Narrowband interference with unknown frequency. In that case you have to maximize stopband attenuation everywhere.
