# How to determined the cutoff frequency of a IIR or FIR

Tags: filters, finite-impulse-response, infinite-impulse-response

I am trying to design a IIR to remove the noise from my input signal. Here is my the my input signal in the frequency domain
[image]

And here is the noise in the frequency domain that,
[image]

So I may choose approximately **60Hz** (might be wrong) as the cutoff frequency based on these two figures, but how should I calculate it?

Answer (score 1):

For filter design, the passband is selected to pass all signals of interest, and the stopband is chosen to select all signals to be rejected. The complexity of the filter is driven by how much distortion to allow in the passband (typically given as a "passband ripple" as a deviation from the ideal "1", how much rejection is required in the stopband, and how much of a transition is given between passband and stopband.

[image: filter specification]

I recommend plotting the magnitude of the spectrums in dB, which will make the distinction between passband and stopband clearer, and allow for reasonable filter design requirements in dB.

This forms the primary trade space of filter design: given the three parameters: filter order, the passband and stopband ripple, and the transition width you can improve two of these at the expense of the third.

For FIR filter design specifically, please see [this post](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/37646/filter-order-rule-of-thumb/37662#37662) on estimating the order required based on the attenuation needed and transition band between passband and stopband.