# Designing of passband and stopband frequencies

Tags: matlab, filter-design, lowpass-filter, infinite-impulse-response

good evening  guys, let us consider following image
[image]

we can see from the picture  designing of lowpass filter  with given passband  region and stopband region, only one thing what i am interesting is why  we   are choosing  passband frequency and stopband frequency far from each other? for instance  let us consider  let us consider following  information  from the  matlab website: Designing of low pass filter and code :

```
For data sampled at 1000 Hz, design a lowpass filter with no more than 3 dB of ripple in a passband from 0 to 40 Hz, and at least 60 dB of attenuation in the stopband. Find the filter order and cutoff frequency.
Wp = 40/500;
Ws = 150/500;

[n,Wn] = buttord(Wp,Ws,3,60)
```

so  here we have Wp(passband frequency) equal to 40 and  stopband frequency  Ws    as 150, we  we have transition band  as  $150-40=110$, but why such  long  transition band?why we can't choose  like  $ws=45$ or something like this? does it affect on order of filter or physical implementation in real life? please explain  it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> why we can't choose like ws=45 or something like this?

You sure can.

> does it affect on order of filter or physical implementation in real life?

It sure does.

> please explain it

The steeper the transition the higher the required filter order will be and the more time domain "ringing" you will get.

This is one of the more fundamental trade offs in filter design: the more aggressive your requirements are in the frequency domain, the more relaxing they have to be in the time domain (and vice versa).

Comment: so it means that  steeper transition  actually  will cause more distortion of signal in time domain? like phase  shifting and so on right? time delay   and  such time domain parameters right

Answer (score 0):

The length and order (complexity) of the filter is dictated by the transition band. The wider you can make the transition band, the shorter you can make the filter for the same passband and stopband ripple.

This is all detailed further at this post showing the relationship between the number of taps in the filter, attenuation and transition bandwidth:

[Filter Order Rule of Thumb](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/37646/filter-order-rule-of-thumb/37662#37662)